# Flask Admin: Format the way relationships are displayed

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I would like to change the way the relationships are displayed in the Flask-Admin Index view of a Model. I do have two models connected through a many-to-many relationship which get displayed in the admin index view as well. Unfortunately, the relationships are just separated using a comma, which thus the user might lose the overview quickly. Ideally, I would like to convert the relationships entries into a simple list (e.g. like with li in HTML).

Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the comma, you can use a `<br>` tag as the separator.
see [column_type_formatters](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_type_formatters).

Define default formatter and update a list type.

```py
def lineby_list_formatter(view, values):
    html = u'<br/> '.join(str(v) for v in values)
    return Markup(html)


MY_DEFAULT_FORMATTERS = dict(typefmt.BASE_FORMATTERS)
MY_DEFAULT_FORMATTERS.update({
    list: lineby_list_formatter
})


class EventView(ModelView):
    ...
    column_type_formatters = MY_DEFAULT_FORMATTERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I figured it out myself: You can manipulate the way the data is rendered with overwriting the function _get_list_value(). see code below

```
    def _get_list_value(self, context, model, name, column_formatters,
                    column_type_formatters):
    """
        Returns the value to be displayed.

        :param context:
            :py:class:`jinja2.runtime.Context` if available
        :param model:
            Model instance
        :param name:
            Field name
        :param column_formatters:
            column_formatters to be used.
        :param column_type_formatters:
            column_type_formatters to be used.
    """
    column_fmt = column_formatters.get(name)
    if column_fmt is not None:
        value = column_fmt(self, context, model, name)
    else:
        value = self._get_field_value(model, name)

    choices_map = self._column_choices_map.get(name, {})
    if choices_map:
        return choices_map.get(value) or value

    type_fmt = None
    for typeobj, formatter in column_type_formatters.items():
        if isinstance(value, typeobj):
            type_fmt = formatter
            break
    if type_fmt is not None:
        value = type_fmt(self, value)

    ### overwritten here

    if name == 'items':

        html_string  = '<ul>'
        for item in value.split(','):
            html_string += '<li> {} </li>'.format(item)
        html_string += '</ul>'
        value = Markup(html_string)


    return value
```

Comment: You should use a column formatter at the view level to achieve this. See [`column_formatters`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters)